# I am trying to filter Merged tickets from reports

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

In reports. I am trying to filter Merged tickets from reports. And I am referring this [solution](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115008191768-Removing-Merged-tickets-from-reports),

does Zendesk made any changes in UI/Options  because I am unable to find options showed in above post to  add matric globally and By  Using Query

```
 SELECT IFNULL((SELECT # Tickets WHERE Ticket Tag = your_tag),0)
```

Is there any other better way to remove merged tickets form Zendesk reports.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you'll want to build the metric yourself as none of that appears to be default. I will share a link to help you:

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/229244588-Reporting-on-ticket-tags

Oh and if the formula you have above is correct but by excluding the closed_by_merge tag would be the best way to exclude merge tickets.